# My WatchKit wkinterfacetable won't scroll

Tags: scroll, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

Despite having more elements than fit the screen I can't seem to get a scroll behavior via touch or scroll wheel in the simulator or actual watch.

[image: Simulator, storyboard]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tables don't behave properly when nested within a group. Remove the group and your tableview should scroll.

The HIG also mentions not to do this: https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/ui-elements/

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Good to understand the reason why too.

Comment: I too have tried to put a table in a group and realised it won't scroll. I have a pages based app with table views all working fine, however the table cells are making the pages indicator difficult to see because they scroll behind it. I was hoping to add a group so that I can size the table to just above the pages indicator. This works and the page indicator is then clearly visible but the table no longer scrolls. I am unable to resize the actual Table can anyone offer a way to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 5):

My one wasn't scrolling because I had "Fixed to screen edges" enabled in the storyboard for that interface controller. Make sure you have that disabled.

[image]

Comment: saved my day. Worked like a charm. This happens in Xcode 11.2 only. In older version no problem

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solution for the table scroll issue in watch app.

1. Remove Table from the Group
2. Other solution that works for displaying indicator is to set Group Size to "Size to fit content"
   Screen shot attached for the reference as well.[image]